# Why do I need to set up Secure Boot password for Ubuntu to install drivers?

Tags: dual-boot, password, secure-boot

Why do I need to set up Secure Boot password for Ubuntu to install drivers?

I installed it with secure boot unchecked, so I don't know if I have those drivers? Firefox seems to tear when scrolling so I think there are some old default linux graphics drivers.

If I set it up, do I need to enter this password every time GRUB loads?

Or is it similar to Windows' BitLocker, only asks for key if somethings changed (f.i. there's connected new USB drive)

Don't know if it matters I dual boot Windows 10 + Ubuntu 19.04

Comment: You don't have to, you *can* disable Secure Boot.